# How do I set my Discord bot activity to the amount of guilds its in?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js and I want to figure out a way that sets the bots activity to "Watching (guild.size) servers" Is there any way to do that? The code I'm trying to squeeze this into is:

```
bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Ready!`);
  //Bot Status
  bot.user.setActivity(`!help`);
```

Comment: Did you have any starting implementation to share ? and tell us what problem you face ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, its

```js
<Client>.user.setActivity(`${<Client>.guilds.size} servers`, { type: "WATCHING" })
```

Comment: When I try to use that it makes my other code break. So if i put that in it says that my other stuff is unexpected or "If" is reserved.

Comment: ```js
bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Ready!`);
  //Bot Status
  bot.user.setActivity(`!help`);
})
```